# Cannot send message to panel in firefox addon? (The page is currently hidden and can no longer be used until it is visible again)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My goal is quite simple: I want a panel where the user can specify username and password and click login. Then I want to do a webrequest to verify the credentials, and show the response to the user.

I figured out that I have to do the request in main.js and pass it back.
So When the form is submitted I build my url, fire a message to main.js where I execute the request. That works fine, the response is also right.
However when I want to send the response back to the panel, I get this error:

```
Error: The page is currently hidden and can no longer be used until it is visible again.
resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/content/worker.js 404
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/net/xhr.js", line 126, in 
    self._orsc.apply(self, arguments);
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/request.js", line 91, in onreadystatechange
    emit(target, 'complete', response);
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/event/core.js", line 83, in emit
    for each (let item in emit.lazy.apply(emit.lazy, arguments)) {
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/event/core.js", line 101, in lazy
    yield listeners.shift().apply(target, args);
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/domain/lib/main.js", line 21, in hosters<.onComplete
    popup.port.emit("handleloginresponse",response);
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/content/worker.js", line 369, in 
    emit: function () self._emitEventToContent(Array.slice(arguments))
  File "resource://jid1-aaautmtqen7pta-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/content/worker.js", line 404, in _emitEventToContent
    throw new Error(ERR_FROZEN);
```

I also tried opening the panel again or using postMessage() instead. Nothing seems to work, I cannot transport back the content into my panel! Any help is appriciated!

This is my main.js

```
var data = require("self").data;

var popup = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 212,
  height: 200,
  contentURL: data.url("popup.html"),
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"),data.url("popup.js")]
});

var Request = require("request").Request;

popup.port.on("handlelogin", function (url) {
    console.log("requesting " + url);
    var hosters = Request({
        url: url,
        onComplete: function (response) {       
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log("emmiting handleloginresponse");
            popup.port.emit("handleloginresponse",response);
        }
    }).get();
}); 

require("widget").Widget({
  label: "my label",
  id: "pop-up",
    contentURL: data.url("16.png"),
  panel: popup
});
```

popup.html

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="loginform">
        <input name="user" placeholder="User" id="userfield" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="passfield"/>
        <input type="submit" id="loginbutton" value="Log in " />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
$('#loginform').submit(function (event) {
    var url = 'https://mydomain.com?user=' + encodeURIComponent($('#loginform')[0].user.value) + '&pass=' + encodeURIComponent($('#loginform')[0].pass.value) + '&something=something;
    self.port.emit("handlelogin",url);

});

self.on("handleloginresponse", function(data) {
    console.log("got a handleloginresponse!");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: turns out that in my case this is unnecessary because it is possible to do ajax requests outside main.js, however in my attempts it did not work because the target url was delivering an error and i did not recieve a success callback. therefore i thought it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem resolved itself as non existend and was caused due to a server side http error